# Naming Ember.js templates with data-template-name

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I've noticed the Ember.js docs explain the way to name templates is by setting the `<script>` tag's `data-template-name` value to the name of the template. But in Tom Dale's latest screencast on the Ember.js documentation site he is naming templates with ids. I assume they are both valid ways to name templates in Ember. Why should one use `data-template-name` as apposed to ids?

Comment: I'd say, no pros, no cons, but id is more concise.

Comment: `data-template-name` or `id` work the same way. What really matters is the name of the template itself, which is what connects the template with the other parts of the app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While both work, using `data-template-name` gives you the freedom of using element ids which won't collide with your template names.

Comment: agreed- also when you move your handlebars templates to stand alone files (production situation lets say) you won't need to worry about id vs data-template-name (let your build tools do this for you based on the template file name)

Comment: @Toran Great point--I had forgotten about build tools and the benefit of using file names in place of `data-template-name` or ids

Comment: so data-template-name and id on template script tags do the exact same thing?

Comment: @ConnorLeech Yes. Ember will look for `data-template-name` first, then for `id`: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/69738fcd698bb2d4230cbef2c8fb65c82bb8d951/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/loader.js#L42

Comment: @zeppelin awesome reference!